# Undefine variable in scope declared by let keyword (angular)

Tags: angular10

My scenario is that when the button is hit, it generate a json variable for being exported. I created local variable call `outputJson` with JSON type using let keyword then try to add non-existing key as following to this code

```
  public generateWorkspace() {
    let outputJson:JSON;
    outputJson['xml-workspace'] = this.blocklyComponent.toXml()
    outputJson['vars-ext'] = this.jsonContent['vars-ext'];
    console.log(outputJson)
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <button (click)="generateWorkspace()">
        Generate Workspace JSON
    </button>
</div>
```

But when `console.log(outputJson)` is execute, Angular throw an error that `outputJson` is undefined.
As per my understanding, let keyword allow block scope access but this has an error despiting that I have declare this variable before and even put some value before printing it out

Please help

Answer (score 0):

> Please define outputJson like below and it will fix your problem.

let outputJson:any={};

Comment: This definitely fix my problem, Thank you sir! But I have a question. Why do let outputJson:JSON and then adding new key with assignment operator does not work. But array of any solve a problem?

Comment: @G.P In your question, you have mentioned - _I created local variable call outputJson with JSON type_. **JSON is not a type. It's an interface and any is a type in typescript.**